Syncing Clerk Data with the Backend Using Webhooks
I've read the documentation: Sync Clerk data to your backend with webhooks | Clerk
I followed through all the steps successfully, the user event webhook I made is succeeding with all the deliveries. Problem is, I still don't get it. What now? How do I actually sync users with my database? I'm using Prisma as an ORM, Neon as the database, and Next.js 14 as the framework.
Webhooks are a new concept to me, to be honest. I did just ask ChatGPT to explain the concept like I'm 5. I kind of get the gist of it but I'm still unsure what to do beyond the last listed step on the documentation.
For more context:
I've made a custom form page for sign up using the useSignUp hook, following the documentation here: useSignUp() and useSignIn() | Clerk
The form in question looks like the one in the screenshot. I want to save the content of the form in the database with Clerk's user Id after Clerk finishes verifying the OTP and creating the user on its end.
I've been stuck on this for 12 hours straight now and I'm honestly getting a bit frustrated at this point.


You need to create an "endpoint" that receives & authenticates the webhook, and then makes the updates in your database.
You could do this by exposing an api route in your application.
As a first step, see if you can write a function that prints the data received by the webhook to the console within your application.
Once you've done that, I'm sure you can figure out how to update the database!
